# JDK8 and Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4)

Tags: oracle, maven

What maven dependency must i have to get the Driver for a Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4) Database in JDK8?

JDK7 works well using ojdbc7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ojdbc7 for Java 8 as well as for Java 7. The [Oracle FAQ says](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03):

> What are the various supported Oracle database version vs JDBC compliant versions vs JDK version supported?
>
> ojdbc7.jar for JDK 8 and JDK 7

Note that this combination is only officially supported for Oracle 12.1 or 12cR1 ("please check with your support channel to check if you are still on the support contract for the older versions."), and that Oracle 10g is no longer supported without [Sustaining Support](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/lifetime-support/index.html) ([lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf) - Oracle 10 Extended Support Ends July 2013).